# What is a DEF function for Python

Tags: python

I am new to coding Python and I just can't seem to understand what a Def function is! I have looked and read many tutorials on it and I still don't quite understand. Can somebody explain to me what it is, what I use it for, and give me some examples. For the examples please make them easy and understandable for a newb to Python. Thanks!

Comment: def is a keyword, used to let python know you are declaring a function definition http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#def

Comment: short for "I'm DEFining a function here" :P

Comment: Try to give more specific details about what confuses you. As is, your question is basically asking us to write you a tutorial, and if the tutorials you've read didn't help, why would we be able to write up a better tutorial on the spot?

Comment: Wow, I am really annoyed that I took the time to answer your question. @user2357112 politely asked what you had tried, as you haven't tried much, nor have you really looked for any resources or you would have known what `def` does. Very disappointing behaviour indeed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`def` isn't a function, it **defines** a function, and is one of the basic keywords in Python.

For example:

```
def square(number):
    return number * number
print square(3)
```

Will display:

```
9
```

In the above code we can break it down as:

- **def** - Tells python we are declaring a function
- **square** - The name of our function
- **(** - The beginning of our arguments for the function
- **number** - The list of arguments (in this case just one)
- **)** - The end of the list of arguments
- **:** - A token to say the body of the function starts now
- The following newline and indent then declare the intentation level for the rest of the function.

It is just as valid (although uncommon) to see:

```
def square(number): return number * number
```

In this case, as there is no indentation the entirety of the function (which in this case is just one line) runs until the end of line. This is uncommon in practise and not considered a good coding style.

Comment: I think it's worth noting here that the line `foo()` is what calls the function, and the `()` is used to tell python that you are calling a function with no arguments.